# JavaScript to read imported CSV tb via jquery and write to another table / part of a site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, csv

I am new to javascript but have a (useless) background in batch scripting, HTML, Powershell, minor PHP, and VBS. So, I apologize in advance if I'm a noob.

The whole plan is as follows:

1. read/import a CSV file to HTML
2. From the CSV data, and write the info from the table to the floor plan of desks

I was able to use jquery to import a CSV file manually (will automate later) to an HTML and have it broken out into a table (TD and TR) in the page and shows all the rows/columns correctly. I import this into a hidden div as it's ugly to look at.

From here, I would like an on click / onload, onhover javascript to pull from that table that was imported to the corresponding desk (desks made from tables) and display information from the table on the desk.

here would be a sample of the csv:

```
PC Name,Date,Time,Online,Admin Access
pcname1,22/12/2016, 8:52:09.49,"Yes","Yes"
pcname2,22/12/2016, 8:52:09.49,"Yes","Yes"
```

The imported through jquery looks like:

```
<table id="contents" style="width:100%; height:400px;" border=""><tbody><tr>
<td>PC Name</td>
<td>Date</td>
<td>Time</td>
<td>Online</td>
<td>Admin Access</td>
<tr>
<td>pcname1</td>
<td>22/12/2016</td>
<td> 8:52:09.49</td>
<td>Yes</td>
<td>Yes</td>
</tr>
```

For the "floorplan" I was going to organize the desks as follows:

```
<td style="border-top; medium none; border-left;
         width: 75px; height: 60px; medium none;" 
    onclick="onBoxClick(this);"  d="pcname1">pcname1</td>
```

How would I write the function to pull from the TD that I have imported to write in the "desk"? Here is an example I copied from another post:

```
function onBoxClick(obj)
{
    var msg_selected;
    for (i=1;i<doctables[pos_tbl].rows.length;i++)
    {
        if (doctables[pos_tbl].rows[i].cells[pos_box].innerHTML == obj.innerHTML)
            msg_selected = 'Selected Seat/Box: ' + obj.innerHTML 
                + '<br/>pcname: ' 
                + doctables[pos_tbl].rows[i].cells[PC Name].innerHTML 
                +'<br/>date: ' 
                + doctables[pos_tbl].rows[i].cells[Date].innerHTML 
                + '<br/>Time: ' 
                + doctables[pos_tbl].rows[i].cells[Time].innerHTML 
                + '<br/>online: ' 
                + doctables[pos_tbl].rows[i].cells[Online].innerHTML 
                + 'Admin ' 
                + doctables[pos_tbl].rows[i].cells[Admin Access].innerHTML;
        document.getElementById('agtInfo').innerHTML=msg_selected
        break;
    }
}
}
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Careful with the last function, you have a `}` that should not be there... take a look at your post as I've make some change ;)

Comment: BTW : `border-top; medium none; border-left; width: 75px; height: 60px; medium none;`  is not a valid CSS declaration, don't mess-up `;` and `:`